# How to iterate nested arrays

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have to iterate nested arrays using react native.

This is the code:

```
<View>
          {
            courses.map(function(course) {
              return (
                <View>
                  <Text>{course.name}</Text>
                </View>
                {course.lessonPlans.map(function(lesson) {
                    return (
                      <View>
                        <Text>{lesson.name}</Text>
                      </View>
                    )
                  })}
              );
            })
          }
</View>
```

When I run this code I get unexpected token ,
How to iterate arrays of arrays using react native ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning adjacent `JSX`. Use `Fragments`:

```
<View>
    {
        courses.map(function (course) {
            return (
                <>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{course.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                    {course.lessonPlans.map(function (lesson) {
                        return (
                            <View>
                                <Text>{lesson.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
                    })
                    }
                </>
            );
        })
    }
</View>
```